# Active Directory 2016 trust issues

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship, admt

I am trying to set up a forest trust and use ADMT to migrate users using this set of instructions; [ADMT Instructions](https://www.pelegit.co.il/admt-active-directory-migration-tool/) .  I am having issues getting the two-way trust to work.  Domain A (testad.domain.org) is not allowing me to add users to the builtin/Administrators group on domain B (target.migrate.org).  I can select domain A trust as a location, but when I go to search for a user it says it cannot find it.  Additionally when I attempt to add Domain A as a nav node in AD Admin Center it says I do not have permissions.  I am able to verify the two way trust without issues.

I've read that firewall may be an issue so I disabled it on both sides temporarily and still the same behavior.

I set up a one-way incoming trust on domain A to domain B.  I was able to add a domain A user to domain B's administrator group, but I was prompted for credentials for a user on Domain A to access the trust.  I can also add domain A as a nav node in AD admin center on domain B.  When I convert the trust to a two-way, it breaks again.

I was able to work through the entire set of instructions on two clean domains, so I know they work.  Additionally, I was never prompted for credentials when adding users to the builtin/Administrators group through the trust both ways.

I'm thinking there is some configuration on domain A (testad.domain.org) that is cuasing the issue.  I can't seem to pinpoint where it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause, it was a UTC time difference between the domains. The system time matched between the domains however the time zones were different. I never saw an error that would cause me to dig deep in to system time up front. I had to set up shares on both sides of the trust, then I got a clock sync error when I attempted to access the share on Domain A from B. Moral of the story; if you suspect a clock issue, check both time and time zones.